# Android SharedPreferences after reboot device

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My English very very BAD cause i'm Russian. :)

In my application I use `SharedPreferences` to store my values.
The data has stored in the `SharedPreferences`, when application is running, and after exit from it. And everything works fine until I reboot my device. After reboot I can't use `SharedPreferences`, and the application doesn't read and write the data from there.
I use the function `getPreferences(0)` to get preferences from application data folder. 
I also tried to use the `getSharedPreferences(myPref, MODE_PRIVATE)`, but the effect is the same. Saves only one solution - data cleaning application after reboot device.

```
    favoriteButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
    SharedPreferences favorite = getSharedPreferences("Favorites", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(favorite.getString(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"", "") == "true") {
        favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_selected));
    } else {
        favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_empty));
    }
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences favorite = getSharedPreferences("Favorites", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = favorite.edit();
            if(favorite.getString(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"", "") == "true") {
                favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_empty));
                Loader.favoriteVideos.remove(Loader.currentVideo);
                editor.remove(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"");
            } else {
                favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_selected));
                Loader.favoriteVideos.add(Loader.currentVideo);
                editor.putString(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"", "true");
            }
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is due to SharedPreferences being killed while reboot. Have a look at [data storage options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: Please post the code you are trying. And logs if you are seeing any issue.

Comment: @Cdr. Powell -- SharedPreferences are stored to a file on the flash drive, and rebooting does not affect that file.

Comment: BarkovAndrey - as @Ankit says, please show your code. Specifically, I'm wanting to know if you're calling the SharedPreferences commit() method, which is required to complete your changes.

Comment: @cdr reboot does not affect SP..  nd barkov u must be doing something wrong... Post ur code...

Comment: I stand corrected. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: I repeat, everything works fine until I reboot device or reinstall application. And helps for it - clear application data.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your advice! But I had solved this problem!
I hope this helps someone, here's a solution.

Before you request a value SharedPreferences, check the availability of keys!!!

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
**sharedpreferences.contains("key")** --- check key!

```
    favoriteButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
    SharedPreferences favorite = getSharedPreferences("Favorites", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tempFav = "";
    if(favorite.contains(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"")) {
        tempFav = favorite.getString(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"", "");
    }
    if(tempFav.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
        favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_selected));
    } else {
        favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_empty));
    }
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences favorite = getSharedPreferences("Favorites", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = favorite.edit();
            String tempCFav = "";
            if(favorite.contains(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"")) {
                tempCFav = favorite.getString(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"", "");
                Log.d(Loader.currentVideo.getTitle());
                Log.d(tempCFav);
            }
            if(tempCFav.equals("true")) {
                favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_empty));
                Loader.favoriteVideos.remove(Loader.currentVideo);
                editor.remove(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"");
            } else {
                favoriteButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_selected));
                Loader.favoriteVideos.add(Loader.currentVideo);
                editor.putString(""+Loader.currentVideo.getTitle()+"", "true");
            }
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if the favorite string has words like subscribe and another option is unsubscribe? .contains will return true. Please see my answer as below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939380/android-persistent-checkable-menu-in-custom-widget-after-reboot-android/36998250#36998250

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work for you to save sharedpreferences. Important part is edit.commit();
If this doesn't work, then might be the phone that you are using has some different behavior as the phone manufacturer may have modified something..

```
private static final String PREFERENCES = "Preferences";
static protected SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences( Context context ) {

    return context.getSharedPreferences( PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void setString(String setting, String value) {

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences( getApplicationContext() );
    Editor edit = settings.edit();
    edit.putString(setting, value);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Comment: This is works and i can see the file with preferences in data folder when my application not run, and after reboot device i see this file!

Comment: But only after reboot my device, my application can't see this file.

Comment: This file continues to hold my values, but when i call getPreferences() after reboot device, can't get and write to this file. And i solve it everything after reboot - clear data my application.

Comment: I'm sorry - my English is very very bad! ((( I'm Russian.

Comment: Which device you use ?  I think some problem with the device. Are you using any custom ROM or stock ROM ? What is android version ?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines  into manifest Application Tag.

android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupContent="true"