# how to configure the session variable on android?

Tags: android, variables, session

I try the sharedPreferences option and works when you don't switch off the tablet or the phone.. in the moment that you turn off the phone all the variables are deleted.

I must save those variables always. But momently, in my present solution, I can't put it to initialized, the user's could have different variable. I must initialized with the last session variables.

How could I do that?

Comment: what? when i save in SharedPreferences, they stay there until the app is uninstalled or I do delete them values by myself... You´re doing something wrong...

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776612/android-sharedpreferences-after-reboot-device ... it might help

Comment: Have You checked my ans ..is it usefull???

Comment: Yes! thanks million! all is working perfectly. Now I have another questions.  Do you know if it is able to save two kinds of sharePreference variable?  What I mean, imagine that I want to save the user details and on the other hand what the user add to the app. But i cant do it in the same variable.